# ¿Cómo llenar una tabla con una array que contiene IDs de una base de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, id

Hola estoy en busca de su sabiduría para solventar el problema en el que estoy implicado. Me explico, tengo una variable en **PHP** del tipo array llamada `$id_total` que almacena **IDs** de equipos guardados en una base de datos **MySQL**. Mi predicamento surge a que necesito llenar una tabla **HTML** con los datos de dichos equipos de acuerdo a las **IDs** que almacena mi variable `$id_total`. Hasta ahora la forma en que generaba las tablas era de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuario 
    JOIN centro_costos ON usuario_centro_costos = centro_costos_id 
    WHERE status_usuario = 'activo'";
$guardar = $conexion->query($consulta);
?>

<table class="table table-sm table-hover table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr class="table-success">
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">
            <input class="busqueda" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            <input class="busqueda" type="text" placeholder="Telefono">
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            <input class="busqueda" type="text" placeholder="Email">
        </th>
        <th>
            <input class="busqueda" type="text" placeholder="Centro de costos">
        </th>
        <th>Editar</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
while($row = $guardar->fetch_assoc())
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb_id[]" value=<?php echo $row['usuario_id']; ?>>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $row ['nombre_usuario'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row ['telefono_usuario'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row ['email_usuario'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row ['nombre_centro_costos'];?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="editar_usuario.php?EDITAR_ID=<?php echo $row['usuario_id']; ?>" 
            class="link-primary" ><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Almaceno la consulta en la variable `$guardar` y después con un `while` lleno la tabla. En resumen me gustaría saber como hacer lo mismo, pero en vez de la variable `$guardar` usar el array `$id_total` o la forma que podría hacerse. Muchas gracias por leer mi pregunta. Cuídense

EDIT:
Por si no quedo claro lo que quiero es llenar la tabla con los valores de equipos almacenados en una base de datos acorde a los **IDs** guardados en mi variable del tipo array `$id_total`.

EDIT 2: Para obtener el `$id_total` es de la siguiente manera, es una array resultante de un `array_diff` que compara una lista de **IDs** seleccionadas de otra tabla con las **IDs** guardadas en la base de datos, basicamente me devuelve las **IDs** que no se seleccionen.

```
<?phpinclude ('conexion.php');
$id_inv = $_GET['EDITAR_ID'];
$consulta_inv = $conexion->query("SELECT id_activo_fijo FROM activo_fijo JOIN inventario_activo_fijo ON relacion_id_activo_fijo = id_activo_fijo JOIN inventario ON relacion_id_inventario = id_inventario WHERE id_inventario = $id_inv");
while ($row = $consulta_inv->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $id_inv_reg[] = $row['id_activo_fijo'];
}
$consulta_activo_fijo =$conexion->query("SELECT id_activo_fijo FROM activo_fijo WHERE status_activo_fijo ='activo'");
while ($rows = $consulta_activo_fijo->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $id_activo_fijo_total[] = $rows['id_activo_fijo'];
}
$id_total = array_diff($id_activo_fijo_total, $id_inv_reg);?>
```

Comment: Nose si entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Lo que quieres hacer es cambiar el `while`, por un `for` para recorrer el array entero?

Comment: Bueno lo que quiero llenar la tabla con los valores de equipos almacenados en una base de datos acorde a los IDs guardados en mi variable del tipo array `$id_total`, si se puede hacer con un `for` no tendría problemas.

Comment: Ya has cargado los valores de los equipos de la base de datos? Como se llama la variable?

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende, hablas de un array `$id_total` que no declaras en ningún lado. En el `while` ya estarías leyendo las filas que te trae la consulta SQL... ¿cuál es el problema en sí y qué es ese famoso `$id_total` que nunca declaras?

Comment: El `$id_total` lo obtengo de un `array_diff()` que me compara dos arrays, una que almacena los **IDs** de una tabla y la otra es de los IDs almacenados en la base de datos, devolviéndome los **IDs** no seleccionados

Comment: Ya he cargado los valores de los equipos desde la base de datos en la variable `$consulta_activo_fijo`

Comment: Intuyo que estás queriendo resolver en PHP un problema que podrías resolver en la base de datos. Lo digo porque veo dos consultas SQL. ¿Por qué no escribes una sola consulta, traes desde ella los datos como los necesitas y luego los lees o los muestras sin más en PHP? ¿Qué justifica que hagas dos consultas? Esto no es bueno desde el punto de vista del rendimiento: se gastan más recursos, no se aprovechan los índices de las tablas, y te ves obligado a seguir organizando los datos en PHP, etc.

Comment: Por lo que estoy entendiendo necesitas consultar la bd según ciertos id que traes mediante un filtro devolviente los id que realmente quieres consultar cierto?

Comment: Claro, esos **IDs** estan almacenados en la variable `$id_total` que es un array, ahora lo que quiero es usar esos mismos **IDs** para llenar una tabla con datos almacenados en una **BD**

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿Se puede hacer algo así? La verdad es que tengo una tabla donde tengo los equipos para seleccionar y recupero los **IDs** que almaceno en una array, pero no sabría hacer lo que me dices directamente en la base de datos, que me devuelva la diferencia entre los **IDs** que seleccione con los que existen almacenados

Comment: Sí, se puede hacer eso y más en la base de datos. De hecho, te aconsejo que no subestimes a la base de datos, la cual no es sólo un almacén de datos sin vida, no, los SGBD son verdaderos sistemas con herramientas potentes para resolver problemas complejos, sin importar que haya decenas o millones de filas guardados en la base de datos. El mayor problema aquí es que no hay claridad en el planteamiento de la pregunta. Inicialmente no se veía que estabas intentando dos consultas y uno de tus últimos comentarios hace pensar que lo que quieres es una especie de *normalización* ...

Comment: ... de los datos (asignar unos IDs que existen en una tabla a otra tabla). Eso se llama *normalización*, y no necesitas PHP para ello, puedes *normalizar* escribiendo una consulta en la base de datos que actualice las filas ya existentes ... ¿y qué pasa con las nuevas filas? pues puedes programar un disparador (`TRIGGER`) en la base de datos, que mantendrá al día las nuevas filas, si lo que quieres es que los IDs de una tabla estén siempre en otra. Resolver un escenario como este en PHP es, como te decía al principio, echarle a PHP un problema que puedes resolver fácilmente en la base de datos